# How to get the user name of thr crm 2011?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-4, dynamics-crm-online

how to Write the javascript function for getting the username(not a owner) in crm 2011.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you mean the `FullName` attribute of a `SystemUser` record you can use this function:

```js
function getCurrentUserFullName() {
    var serverUrl;
    if (Xrm.Page.context.getClientUrl !== undefined) {
        serverUrl = Xrm.Page.context.getClientUrl();
    } else {
        serverUrl = Xrm.Page.context.getServerUrl();
    }
    var ODataPath = serverUrl + "/XRMServices/2011/OrganizationData.svc"; 
    var userRequest = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
    userRequest.open("GET", ODataPath + "/SystemUserSet(guid'" + Xrm.Page.context.getUserId() + "')", false); 
    userRequest.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json"); 
    userRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8"); 
    userRequest.send();
    if (userRequest.status === 200) {
        var retrievedUser = JSON.parse(userRequest.responseText).d; 
        var userFullName = retrievedUser.FullName;
        return userFullName;
    }
    else {
        return "error";
    }
}
```

reference: [CRM Answers - Get current user's full name with a synchronous call](http://www.crmanswers.net/2013/04/get-current-users-full-name-with.html)

Answer (score 2):

```
Xrm.Page.context.getUserId();
```

This returns the GUID of the current user.
Query the User entity with the retrieved GUID to retrieve the name and any other details associated with the user.